# Portable Library Service Reference

Tags: c#, wcf, portable-class-library

I created a WCF service and a portable class library.  I added a service reference to the service from the library.  I noticed that it only generated async methods.  After further inspection, some options are disabled in the create service reference dialog advanced options.  Options such as the access level( defaults to public ), and "Allow generation of asynchronous operations"

Is this a limitation in a portable class library?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the restriction to only async is because the portable libraries can target silverlight, which doesn't support non-async code. The access level might be similar.